# ffmpeg generating a blank video as output of a screen capture

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, screen-capture

I'm trying to record as video a screen but it's a blank video as output. I'm using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 25 -i title=calc fo.flv
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Share the full console output. Blind guess is that you need to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` before `fo.flv` Which player are you testing in?

Comment: I'm new to ffmpeg, does it record to video players only? I'm not testing with one... the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` returned not found

Comment: No, it saves to files. You mentioned "a blank video as output". What did you view the file in?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean, "does it record *only* video players window?" e.g, can I use it with any kind of Window, such as a calculator? the video output is just a black screen where the only thing that seems to be recorded was the mourse cursor

Comment: No. it can record any window. Try `title=Calculator`

Comment: I've tried it, the video output is the previously one I mentioned.

Comment: If I try record for example MS word window, I get: `invalid properties, aborting`

Comment: Share the full console output.

Comment: Here's: console output http://pastebin.com/t7VURySg and video: https://vid.me/fIPM (I'm clicking on buttons 3, +, and 3 a couple of times but only cursor gets recorded)

Comment: [gdigrab @ 02edb100] Failed to capture image (error 8) happens when I close the window. I don't know other way to stop the ffmpeg recording

Comment: Press `q` or `Ctrl-C` to stop recording, when the focus is on the ffmpeg terminal window.  Does `-i desktop` work?

Comment: Yes, `-i desktop` does work fine.

Comment: @Mulvya It isn't working but thosw WIndows' (some native) programs I tested: calc.exe, notepad.exe, MS word, Firefox, Windows Media Player but it works for k-lite video player. It didn't find much of windows by title that I've tried either. I guess it didn't support unicode too? from that source file (https://github.com/WatchBeam/ftl-ffmpeg/blob/master/libavdevice/gdigrab.c) it seems to be using an ANSI string (if the exe I'm using came from that same source)

Comment: @Mulvya: Are you using Windows? do recording the Windows' native calculator program work on your machine?

Comment: It works [here](https://vid.me/HY6i). But the mouse isn't recorded correctly.

Comment: Weird. I see you're on Win7, I'm on win10... I'll try on win7 machine to see if make any difference. `ffmepg` doesn't accept unicode file names either, I'm almost giving up `ffmepg`...

Comment: Since desktop works, you can capture and crop at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7718

From the comments on the issue, it has to do with GPU rendering.